# Ruby Array limit method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to limit an Array object. How is this possible with ruby

```
['one','two','three'].limit(2) => ['one','two']
```

Thanks for your quick help!

Comment: Do you want to limit the size of the original array?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The [Array#take](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) method is probably what you want.

```
['one','two','three'].take(2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!
Found another solution too: ['one','two','three'][0..1] => ["one", "two"]

Answer (score 41):

You have [Array#first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-first):

```
['one','two','three'].first(2)
=> ['one', 'two']
```

Answer (score 8):

```
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3,4,5].slice! 0,4
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Just another way to do it.

Comment: I like how this one is destructive.